# Celery task Priority with redis backend in Flask

Tags: flask, celery

Below is my simplified website app and celery setup

```
app = Flask(__name__)
celery = Celery(__name__, broker='redis://localhost:6379/0') 
celery.conf.update({app.config})
```

and other celery configs are

```
CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD=1 
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=['json','pickle']
```

I have two tasks, one is taking a lot of CPU and Memory resources and need a long time to be finished(which I want to set it priority to "low"), and the other one is just to send email for account verification(which I want to set it priority to "high"), defined as below,

```
@celery.task(serializer='pickle') 
def long_big_task_with_low_priority(...):
    ...   

@celery.task(serializer='pickle') 
def send_email_with_high_priority(...):
    ...
```

I use supervisord to execute the celery

```
celery worker -A celerytaskfile.celery --loglevel=error --concurrency=2 --logfile=celerylogfile.log
```

because the first task consuming lots of resources, therefore I make concurrency 2 here.

**My question is when there are two first tasks running, and now celery receives a new task to send email, is it possible to make the send-mail task executed immediately, and then after it completed continue with the first two tasks?**

Package Version: Celery:4.1.0  redis==2.10.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need two workers. One will only process `long_big_task_with_low_priority` and the other the rest of the (fast running) tasks. For that you will need a separate queue for the `long_big_task_with_low_priority` task.

Use `CELERY_TASK_ROUTES` (`CELERY_ROUTES` for older celery versions) to route the slow task to a new queue.

```
CELERY_TASK_ROUTES = {
    'long_big_task_with_low_priority': {'queue': "slow_queue"},
}
```

When running the workers, assign queues (important for both because otherwise they will consume tasks from any queue)

celery is the default queue name - all tasks go there by default:

```
celery worker -A celerytaskfile.celery --queues celery
```

second worker:

```
celery worker -A celerytaskfile.celery --queues slow_queue
```

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#task-routes
https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#queues